# The four letters YHVH

Tags: word, english

> What is the most commonly used everyday English word that contains the four letters **YHVH** in some order?

Explanation:

- The answer is unique and clear, unless you try hard to stretch the rules that are explained in the following lines.
- contains letters **YHVH** = contains those 4 letters (in some order) and some other letters (in some order)
- the word must not contain any special symbols (like hyphens) nor blanks
- "everyday English word" = contained in this form as the main entry in most/all
  the standard dictionaries
- in particular adverbs like overthoughtfully, overchildishly, thievishly do not count as they are not the main entry
- in particular words like vasorrhaphy, orthoveratraldehyde, phosphorylative do not count as they are not everyday words

Comment: -1 "Standard dictionaries" in not specific at all, and the rules seem to keep changing once people find words that aren't the one the OP was thinking of.

Comment: @Geobits I'm not sure if he's moving the goalposts or painting the target, but whatever it is, it's annoying.

Comment: Grepping /usr/share/dict shows 19 words with those letters, of which at least four currently meet your ever-narrowing definition.

Comment: N.b. my favorite is 'everywhither'.

Comment: @Kevin: I checked /usr/share/dict before posting this puzzle. I did not consider "everywhither" and "overhaughty" to fit the description "everyday English word".

Comment: @Haobin: You should better have written: "What is the most commonly used everyday English word ..."

Comment: "The answer is unique and clear (unless you try hard to stretch the rules)" Actually, the answer is not unique unless you keep changing the rules to exclude unwanted answers, as your seven-and-counting narrowing edits make clear.

Comment: Interesting. After so-and-so-many edits and rewritings, your question seems to have turned into something reasonable.

Comment: Even though there are edge cases of words found in some dictionaries and not others, I think closing for broadness is taking it too far. There are other puzzles that involve more subjective judgments. Downvotes are the way to go if you dislike the subjectivity.

Comment: @xnor: I agree that this should be reopenend.  My first comment (above) was not meant in a negative way. The author started out with a bad formulation, and eventually managed to improve it. I even think that now "heavyweight" is the clear answer.

Comment: Fun fact: YHVH is a tetragrammaton. It's the Hebrew name of God.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about **heavyweight**? I'm still confused on how this is a puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

There does not appear to be a unique answer.

Possible answers include **h**ea**vy**weig**h**t, t**h**ie**v**is**h**l**y**, and **h**ea**vyh**earted.

Comment: "heavyweight" is correct, but a dictionary would contain "thievish" instead of "thievishly" and "heavy-hearted" instead of heavyhearted.

Comment: "Thievishly" *does* appear in dictionaries, just not as a main entry. That's like ruling out plurals or tenses.

Comment: @Haobin Merriam-Webster has "heavyhearted" without a hyphen. And while "thievish" is the main entry, it also contains the adverbial form "thievishly".

Comment: @Haobin Making people guess what dictionaries you're using isn't normally a good idea.

Comment: @Haobin I don't have 4-5 dictionaries laying around. I can do a web search, but I guess [I don't know](http://www.yourdictionary.com/thievishly) what [counts as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thievishly) a ["standard" dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/thievishly), so I can only guess. [More](http://www.finedictionary.com/thievishly.html), [more](http://dictionary.kids.net.au/word/thievishly), [and more](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/thievishly) examples can be found.

Comment: @Haobin Which was fine under the original question. It is only disallowed because you edited the question to exclude it. You're moving the goalposts.

Comment: @Haobin, The OED (which is the authoritative dictionary for British English) has main entry "[Thievishly, adv.: In a thievish manner; as a thief; furtively, by stealth.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200753)" "thievishly, adv." OED Online. Oxford University Press, December 2014. Web. 10 February 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Except the answers already provided, 2 other words I found are:

- superheavyweight
- phosphorylative

Comment: phosphorylative might not be, however superheavyweight is. I have checked up superheavyweight in a couple of dictionaries I have.

Comment: *Superheavyweight* is in Merriam-Webster, Collins, and Oxford at the least.

Comment: Oxford and Collins are the ones I have! :P

Comment: In your other comment you said to check 4-5. I checked 5, and it's there in **most** (60%) of them, just as you specified.

Comment: It should be a valid answer in that case, shouldn't it?

Comment: It should be, but the OP seems to think that any answer other than the intended one is somehow cheating, and that the number of alternate answers reveals a bunch of cheaters, rather than a poor question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more to contribute to the holes:

- everywhither
- heavy-handed